# how can i change Date picker calendar (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, datepicker

I changed computer's culture and date to non-Gregorian (Thai) calendar but JavaScript (`new Date`) keeps giving me the Gregorian date.

Comment: How about the language of the browser you're using? Did you change it to Thai?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start check out for `toLocaleDateString` method, I will use it in example later.

> For different languages:

1. "en-US": For English "
2. hi-IN": For Hindi
3. "ja-JP": For Japanese

You can use more language options.

***Take a look at this code example:***

```
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var today  = new Date();

console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US")); // 9/17/2016
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)); // Saturday, September 17, 2016
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("hi-IN", options)); // शनिवार, 17 सितंबर 2016
```

Comment: Thanx Roxy, i want use Thai calendar(+543) in JS , expected: new Date(); returns Date in Thai calendar (14/12/2561 Friday)

Comment: @bedouikhalil as in my example you can say new Date() and convert it to toLocaleDateString("thai values");

Comment: the Date picker i am using takes the new Date as "Value" i and (today.toLocaleDateString("en-US")) returns a string .